# R command that returns the components of a function?

Tags: r

Suppose I have `fit=lm(y~x)`. What's the R command that shows me the components of `fit`? I remember that if I were to run `mystery_Rcommand(fit)`, then the console would return a list of components such as "fitted.values", "residuals", "coefficients" etc. Knowing these components will allow me to do `fit$fitted.values` and look at the fitted values and what not. But I just can't remember what that R command is. Can anyone help?

Comment: Perhaps, you're looking for `?str`, `?unclass`?

Comment: I'd often use `attributes(fit)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fitted()`, `resid()`, `coef()`, ..., will extract the components. `methods(class = "lm")` will show you more.

`str()` will show you the structure of the model fit, the components of the list. `?lm` will tell you what components should be in an object returned by `lm()`.

An example, from `?lm`:

```
## Annette Dobson (1990) "An Introduction to Generalized Linear Models".
## Page 9: Plant Weight Data.
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
lm.D9 <- lm(weight ~ group)

str(lm.D9)
coef(lm.D9)
fitted(lm.D9)
```

Producing (edited):

```
> str(lm.D9)
List of 13
 $ coefficients : Named num [1:2] 5.032 -0.371
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "groupTrt"
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:20] -0.862 0.548 0.148 1.078 -0.532 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:20] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ effects      : Named num [1:20] -21.674 -0.83 0.197 1.127 -0.483 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:20] "(Intercept)" "groupTrt" "" "" ...
 $ rank         : int 2
 $ fitted.values: Named num [1:20] 5.03 5.03 5.03 5.03 5.03 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:20] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ assign       : int [1:2] 0 1
 $ qr           :List of 5
....
> coef(lm.D9)
(Intercept)    groupTrt 
      5.032      -0.371 
> fitted(lm.D9)
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13 
5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 5.032 4.661 4.661 4.661 
   14    15    16    17    18    19    20 
4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661 4.661
```

Comment: `summary(lm.D9)` is also worth looking at but I usually use `str(lm.D9)` for the the particular issue in the question

Comment: It sounds like they may have also just been using `names(fit)` to get the names of list items and not necessarily all the values. But all these functions are useful at different times.